# Identity Server 3 implicit grant with mvc application

Tags: security, openid-connect, identityserver3

According to openid spec: Implicit grant is suitable javascript and mobile applications and it is less secure compare with authorization code grant. In other words; as far as i understand, it is not recomended for server based application(like aspnet mvc).

> The Implicit Flow is mainly used by Clients implemented in a browser
>   using a scripting language

But, i have seen some examples using implicit grant with mvc application(for example: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc). So i am confused.

Is it correct(secure) using implicit grant with mvc application especially sso purpose?

If not; is there an owin middleware for mvc client application to handle authorization code flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If all you're doing is authentication then implicit is fine. If you're also obtaining access tokens then implicit exposes those to the browser and user. So if you plan to use that access token in your JS, then no worries -- the API is already designed to be accessed from the browser directly. But if you prefer that your API is not accessible from the browser, then hybrid flow will prevent the access token from being made visible to the browser, JS, and user.

Comment: my purpose is only authenticate mvc applications, the answer is satisfactory. However, as far as  i know with implicit flow identity server sends tokens to browser directly with hash fragment. When i try mvc client sample with implicit grant, i see that browser immediately sends tokens to mvc client application for setting cookie. how does it happen?

Comment: How does what happen?

Comment: i couldn't understand how does identity server redirect browser to client application after user authentication.

Comment: Because the client redirect URI is pre-registered with IdSvr.

Comment: Does identity server send 302 response to make it?

Comment: Depends on the `response_mode´ parameter - the recommended way is to use a form post.